# How can I use same view file for different role types in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I am creating a module to ToDo list. If the role type is admin, she/he can assign ToDo to any user. However, if a normal user creates a ToDo, it will automatically, be assigned to current user. I implemented like below:

ToDoController function looks like below:

```
public function create()
    {

        return view('todo.create',['countries' => Country::all(), 'business_types' => BusinessType::all(), 'users' => User::all()]);
    }
```

The view file create.blade.php with user selection select box is as below:

```
            @if(!empty(Auth::user()->roles()->where('name','admin')->first()))
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Assigned To</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="user_id">
                        @foreach ($users as $user)
                          @if ($user->id == old('user_id'))
                            <option value="{{$user->id}}" selected>{{$user->name}}</option>
                          @else
                            <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                          @endif                                  
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @if ($errors->has('user_id'))
                      <div class="alert-danger">
                        <p>{{ $errors->first('user_id') }}</p>
                      </div>
                    @endif
                  </div>
                @else
                  <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                    <label for="description">Assigned To</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="user_id">
                        <option value="{{$user->id}}" selected>{{$user->name}}</option>
                    </select>
                    @if ($errors->has('user_id'))
                      <div class="alert-danger">
                        <p>{{ $errors->first('user_id') }}</p>
                      </div>
                    @endif
                  </div>
                @endif
```

In the case of normal user, it is not required to take all users value, but I can't avoid that. Is there any optimized method to implement the same this ?

Thanks in Advance !
Manu

Comment: what is your output for your if condition in admin and normal user?

Comment: If, it is admin...as in above view code, it will list all user name...if it is a normal user, only the current user will be in the list and it will be hidden

Comment: if it may be a hidden field, why not: '@'else <input type="hidden" name='user_id' value={{$user->id}}/> '@'endif instead of not displaying all that select element? that would certainly be and optimization. If not, maybe add Auth::id() in your php code instead of coding it in the view? taking user id from the view seems only like a risk for users to manipulate input to me (not much they can do with it anyway I guess...)